# Google Maps API v3 is not rerendering directions correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a small test project in here: http://jsfiddle.net/jochenhebbrecht/k3a3fvq0/3/

I clean routes using the following method:

```
// Clean previous routes
if (directionsDisplays.length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < directionsDisplays.length; i++) {
        directionsDisplays[i].setMap(null);
    }
    directionsDisplays.length = 0;
}
```

I draw routes using the follow method:

```
// Draw all routes
if (routes.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
            var route = routes[i];
            var request = {
                origin: route.origin,
                destination: route.destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
                waypoints: route.waypoints
            };

            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                suppressMarkers: true,
                preserveViewport: true,
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeColor: '#C6D300'
                }
            });
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);

            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

I have a checkbox which show some routes on a map. If you check the box, routes are shown. If you uncheck the box, routes are removed.

However, if I check the box again (for a second time), not all routes are rendered correctly. You have to check/uncheck a couple of times to let it work ...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that.

Update your code as shown below and you will see what happens:

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
} else {
    alert(status);
}
```

You will get several `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` status messages.

More information can be found here:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsStatus

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it was indeed the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT!

Answer (score 1):

Check the status returned by your directions requests.  If they fail due to OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, delay a short while and retry the failed requests.
Also, don't request the routes every time they are displayed, if they are already available redisplay the route.

Note that the approach above will only work for the same order of magnitude of routes you currently have, if you have a *lot* more routes it will be prohibitively slow.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yadoLj2a/1/)

```
function highlightRoutes() {
  if (directionsDisplays.length > 0 && (directionsDisplays[0].getMap() == null)) {
    // redisplay the routes 
    for (var i = 0; i < directionsDisplays.length; i++) {
      directionsDisplays[i].setMap(map);
    }
  } else if (directionsDisplays.length > 0 && (directionsDisplays[0].getMap() != null)) {
    // hide the routes 
    for (var i = 0; i < directionsDisplays.length; i++) {
      directionsDisplays[i].setMap(null);
    }
  } else {
    var routes = new Array();

    if (jQuery('#chkBxBikeRoutes').attr('checked')) {
      routes.push.apply(routes, getBikeRoutes());
    }

    // Clean previous routes
    if (directionsDisplays.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < directionsDisplays.length; i++) {
        directionsDisplays[i].setMap(null);
      }
      directionsDisplays.length = 0;
    }

    // Draw all routes
    if (routes.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
          var route = routes[i];
          var request = {
            origin: route.origin,
            destination: route.destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
            waypoints: route.waypoints
          };

          var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            suppressMarkers: true,
            preserveViewport: true,
            polylineOptions: {
              strokeColor: '#C6D300'
            }
          });
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          directionsDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);

          directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            } else if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
              //document.getElementById("status").innerHTML += request.origin+":"+request.destination+"status:"+status+"<br>";
              setTimeout(function() {
                directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                  } else {
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML += request.origin + ":" + request.destination + "status:" + status + "<br>";
                  }
                })
              }, 2000);
            } else {
              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML += request.origin + ":" + request.destination + "status:" + status + "<br>";
            }
          });
        })(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```